# Cordova Push Notification not opening App on Android (Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of)

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I am trying to implement Push Notifications in an Cordova application. I do receive the push notifications but nothing happens when I click on them.
I see the following message in logcat when clicking on it:

```
I/ActivityManager(  746): START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=xx.xxx.xx/jp.wizcorp.phonegap.plugin.localNotification.AlarmHelper (has extras)} from uid 10185 on display 0
W/InputMethodManagerService(  746): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@210f434 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@9fef9f7
```

I am using the following plugin for push notifications https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-localNotifications

And as far as I can tell this is the relevant part:

```
// Create onClick for toast notification
        Intent onClick = new Intent(context, AlarmHelper.class)
            .putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
        // Create pending intent for onClick
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, onClick, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        // Build Notification
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(bundle.getInt(ICON))
            .setContentTitle(bundle.getString(TITLE))
            .setContentText(bundle.getString(SUBTITLE))
            .setTicker(bundle.getString(TICKER_TEXT))
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 100, 200, 300 })
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .build();
```

copied from [here](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-localNotifications/blob/master/platforms/android/src/jp/wizcorp/phonegap/plugin/localNotification/AlarmReceiver.java#L47-L63)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I had to include the Intent's activity in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Adding this line solved it.

```
<activity android:name="jp.wizcorp.phonegap.plugin.localNotification.AlarmHelper" />
```

Always make sure any time you're referencing an activity in an Intent that it's included in your manifest.